# Interchange order of integral

Tags: calculus

Can someone tell me which step in the process did wrong? My result seems wrong
$$D = \{(x, y) \mid \sqrt{2x - x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{2x}, 0 \leq x \leq 2 \}$$
$$\iint_D f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$$
Then I can draw the Graph
[image]

According to the graph, we can know that this is the area enclosed by $x = \frac{y^2}{2}$ and $x = 2$ minus the semicircle area
$$\iint_D f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = -\int_0^4 \int_{\frac{y^2}{2}}^2 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy - 2\int_0^1 \int_1^{1 + \sqrt{1 - y^2}} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy $$

Comment: May be I do not understand your working fully. $y^2 = 2x$ then how do you get $y = 4$ for $x = 2$? Next - why would you integrate over $x$ first when it is simpler to do over $y$ first?

Comment: Yes you are right, I just made a simple calculation error, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way to write the iterated integral is of course $$\iint_D f \, dA = \int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2x}} f \, dy \, dx.$$  The first alternative where the order of integration is switched, is as you attempted, the area of the parabolic sector minus the semicircle.  Note that the parabolic segment satisfies $$y = \sqrt{2x} \iff x = \frac{y^2}{2},$$ so when $x = 2$, $y = \sqrt{4} = 2$, not $y = 4$ as shown in your diagram.  Then the semicircular arc is a portion of the circle $y^2 = 2x - x^2 = 1 - (x-1)^2$, hence $$x = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 - y^2}.$$  Thus the semicircular region is, for $y \in [0,1]$, bounded above by $1 + \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ and below by $1 - \sqrt{1 - y^2}$, and we have
$$\iint_D f \, dA = \int_{y=0}^2 \int_{x=y^2/2}^2 f \, dx \, dy - \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=1 - \sqrt{1 - y^2}}^{1 + \sqrt{1 - y^2}} f \, dx \, dy.$$  A second alternative is to compute the area from $y = 0$ to $1$ as the sum of two sub-areas, plus a third sub-area from $y = 1$ to $2$:  $$\iint_D f \, dA = \int_{y=0}^1 \left( \int_{x=y^2/2}^{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}} f \, dx + \int_{x=1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}^2 f \, dx \right) dy + \int_{y=1}^2 \int_{x=y^2/2}^2 f \, dx \, dy.$$

Comment: I also made a simple calculation error,Thank！

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what function $f$ is, but your last equality is right **if** the integral of $f$ over the left half of the semicircle equals the integral over the right half. But not otherwise.

Comment: Just exchange the order of integration, $f$ can be any function, do you know how to modify if I want to holds for all functions $f$?

Comment: Instead of going from the vertical line to the right half of the circle, just go from the left halv of the circle to the right half:
$$ \iint_D f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = -\int_0^4 \int_{\frac{y^2}{2}}^2 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy - \int_0^1 \int_{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{1 + \sqrt{1 - y^2}} f(x,y) \,dx\,dy $$

Comment: Yes you are right, And I also made a simple calculation error,Thank！